# Is there a way to use remap_pfn_range() to get hugepages?

Tags: linux-kernel, huge-pages

I have booted Linux with a portion of memory reserved (i.e. booted it with 8GB for linux and 8GB unused).

I know the physical address of the unused memory. From a kernel module I want to map these physical pages into the virtual address space of some process. I can use remap_pfn_range() to do this and it works fine.

But I'd like to use hugepages instead of regular 4KB pages. I have reserved sufficient hugepage entries on the linux side. How can I map the physical memory as hugepages in virtual address space for the user? As far as I can tell remap_pfn_range() has no way to do this.